# My output in verilog is high impedance all the time. Why is that?

Tags: verilog, adder, high-impedance

I am new to verilog and I have been writing code for 4 bit adder/substractor in structural model. My values of `x0,x1,x2,x3,c1,c2,c3,cb` and `sd[0:3]` are all stubbornly high impedance i.e. z. Can anyone please help me? My code is -->

```
module fa (output s,c, input x,y,z);

        assign s=x^y^z;
        assign c= (x&y)|(y&z)|(z&x);
endmodule

module xor1 (output m, input k,l);

        assign m=k^l;
endmodule


module addsub (output [0:3]sd ,output cb, input [0:3]a ,input [0:3]b ,input sel);

wire c1,c2,c3,x0,x1,x2,x3; 


xor1 z0(x0,a[0],sel);

xor1 z1(x1,a[1],sel);

xor1 z2(x2,a[2],sel);

xor1 z3(x3,a[3],sel);

fa z4(sd[0],c1,x0,b[0],sel);

fa z5(sd[1],c2,x1,b[1],c1);

fa z6(sd[2],c3,x2,b[2],c2);

fa z7(sd[3],cb,x3,b[3],c3);    

endmodule
```

Comment: Please, please, please give your wires sensible names. It doesn't take long to type a few extra characters! Where is your testbench code? Don't use 'z' or 'x' as single letter variable names as it is easy to confuse them with constant values of high-impedance and don't care respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the problem is with your test bench. I've just created the following test bench and it outputs non-z values for your design:

```
module testbench;
    wire [3:0] sd;
    wire cb;

    reg [3:0] a, b;
    reg sel;

    addsub uut (
        .sd(sd),
        .cb(cb),
        .a(a),
        .b(b),
        .sel(sel)
    );

    integer i;
    initial begin
        for (i = 0; i < 2**9; i=i+1) begin
            {a, b, sel} = i; #1;
            $display("a=%-2d b=%-2d sel=%d -> sd=%-2d cb=%d", a, b, sel, sd, cb);
        end
    end
endmodule
```